# Как использовать define внутри вложенной структуры?

Tags: c

Есть некая структура, описанная в заголовочном файле.

```
typedef struct i_str  
{  
    int index;
#define ERR_N_1  0  
    int err_n_1;
    int stat_index;   
    struct   
    {  
#define STATE_N_1 0  
        int state_n_1;  
    } state;  
} i_str
```

В основном файле есть другая функция, которая выводит эту структуру, сравнивая индекс с номером ошибки с помощь какой-нибудь функции `comp(a, b)`:

```
void i_str_dump(struct i_str *msg)  
{
    if(comp(msg->index , ERR_N_1))
        printf("Error_1: %i", msg->err_n_1);
    if(comp(msg->stat_index, STATE_N_1))
        printf("state 1: %i", msg->state.state_n_1);
}
```

И вот оно не компилируется, проблема в `#define STATE_N_1 0`. Почему-то этот define не воспринимается компилятором. Как мне обратиться к нему, ничего не меняя в заголовочном файле?

Comment: перенесите все #define в глобальную область кода (до объявления структуры) чтобы она действовала во всем коде

Comment: а что именно пишет?

а в "основном файле" есть `#define STATE_N_1 0`  ? я не проверял но возможно сначала дефайн отрабатывает в заголовочном файле а уже потом результат дописывается в основной файл...

Comment: И что за проблема? Компилятор так на чистом русско-английском и заявляет: проблема с `#define STATE_N_1 0` ?

Кстати, там, в заголовочном файле точки с запятой в конце не хватает.

Comment: Да ничего не пишет, куча wrong'ов но ни одной error. Просто при сборке уже вылетает и все.

Comment: попробуйте эти же #define вставить перед void i_str_dump (struct i_str *msg) повторно

Comment: Опять просьба вылечить от подземного стука. Стандартный ответ: ПСНЛ (подземный стук не лечим).

Comment: alexlz, чувак, ты о чем? Какой подземный стук? Я про дефайны спрашиваю, если не можешь помочь, то не лезь.

Comment: Так. Проблему описать не могём, как ругается компилятор -- не говорим, на вопросы обижаемся. Чувак, ты не прав. Хочешь, чтобы помогли, не изображай партизана в плену у немцев. Куски текста и сообщения компилятора -- в студию.

Comment: Понимаешь, это дело компилируется и собирается, ошибки не отображаются, только ворнинги. Компилятор вообще молчит насчет этого. Ошибку выводит уже make, что-то типа make[2]: *** [../home/message.o] Error 1

Comment: Просто Error 1? Круто. Но увы, т. Станиславский научил всех говорить "Не верю".
И, кстати, в нормальной программе ворнингов быть не должно.

Comment: @bunch, поймите, на весь Ваш код, включая Makefile смотреть неохота, поэтому ответьте не простой вопрос:

Почему Вы решили, что 

     проблема в #define STATE_N_1 0

в то время как `make` сообщает `Error 1`, а все остальное (как Вы утверждаете) к делу не относится?

Comment: @avp, когда я комментил этот дефайн - все прекрасно собиралось и работало. Ну естественно вместо него в comp подставлял его значение.

Comment: @bunch, остается предположить, что где-то в коде  есть условная трансляция, что-то вроде:

    #ifndef STATE_N_1  // или #ifdef ...
       .....
    #else
       .....
    #endif

Посмотрите, как делается message.o, на который ругается make.

Еще вариант, что в message.c есть переменная с именем STATE_N_1, которая заменяется на 0, файл не компилируется, а Вы это не замечаете.

Answer (score 3):

[@bunch](/users/11269/bunch), если собрать представленные фрагменты Вашего кода и  добавить в начало `#include <stdio.h>`, а  **символ `;` после `i_str`** , то

gcc -c нормально компилирует, а g++ естественно ругается на необъявленную `comp()`.

```
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ gcc define.c -c
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ echo $?
0
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ g++ define.c -c
define.c: In function ‘void i_str_dump(i_str*)’:
define.c:18:31: error: ‘comp’ was not declared in this scope
define.c:20:38: error: ‘comp’ was not declared in this scope
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$
```

А расположение `#define STATE_N_1 0` тут ни при чем.

Если идет ругань, типа:

```
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ gcc define.c -c
define.c:13:0: warning: "STATE_N_1" redefined [enabled by default]
define.h:1:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$
```

то это означает, что идентификатор был уже определен ранее (например, во включаемом .h файле) с **другим значением**.